# converting three chanel image to single channel image

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

am using hough transform for detecting circles in the real time video frame.in hough circles function the first parameter is to pass as an single channel image.i dont know how to do this. it continously shows error in that part.

the code am using :

```
import cv2
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import imread
import numpy as np

fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
cam_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
upper_left = (50, 50)
bottom_right = (300, 300)

def sketch_transform(image):
##    print(image)
##    print("2")
##    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
##    print(image)
##    print("3")
##    gray = 255-gray
##    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
##    image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
##    print(image)
##    print("4")
##    #image = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1,(0,0,255),3)
##    print(image)
##    print("4")
    circle_detect(image)

    return image

def circle_detect(image):
    #image1=str(image)
    #mage = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    print (image)
    print("k")
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=90,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=100)
    print(circles)

    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
##    for i in circles[0,:]:
##        # draw the outer circle
##        cv2.circle(image,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
##        # draw the center of the circle
##        cv2.circle(image,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
    return circles




while True:
    _, image_frame = cam_capture.read()

    #Rectangle marker
    r = cv2.rectangle(image_frame, upper_left, bottom_right, (100, 50, 200), 5)
    rect_img = image_frame[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] : bottom_right[0]]

    sketcher_rect = rect_img
    print(sketcher_rect)
    print("1")
    sketcher_rect = sketch_transform(sketcher_rect)

    #Conversion for 3 channels to put back on original image (streaming)
    #sketcher_rect_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(sketcher_rect, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

    #Replacing the sketched image on Region of Interest
    image_frame[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] : bottom_right[0]] = sketcher_rect
    cv2.imshow("Sketcher ROI", image_frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13:
        break

cam_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

am new to opencv and i have been struggling for last four days for detecting circles in a video frame.as an image the detction is good but it make some trouble in video frame.

the output is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/Pi-tracker-master/fgroi.py", line 62, in <module>
    sketcher_rect = sketch_transform(sketcher_rect)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/Pi-tracker-master/fgroi.py", line 27, in sketch_transform
    circle_detect(image)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/Pi-tracker-master/fgroi.py", line 36, in circle_detect
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.4) /home/pi/packaging/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.hpp:255: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::CvtHelper<VScn, VDcn, VDepth, sizePolicy>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) [with VScn = cv::Set<1>; VDcn = cv::Set<3, 4>; VDepth = cv::Set<0, 2, 5>; cv::SizePolicy sizePolicy = (cv::SizePolicy)2u; cv::InputArray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 3
```

Comment: i cant understand what you are saying'

Comment: `image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)` this line should use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` ... The image is in BGR and you want it to be in GREYscale. Note that OpenCV uses BGR by default and not RGB

Comment: i changed that one but it not works